# email with list of failed mounts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am learning Scripting,
I came across this script

```
#!/bin/bash

A=`awk '{print $2}' /etc/fstab | grep -i "^/" | egrep -v '/etc/fstab|proc|sys|shm|pts'`

for i in $A; do grep "$i" /proc/mounts > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $i "TRUE"
    else
        echo $i "FALSE"
    fi
done
```

Is there way to send  an email with the list of mounts which are Not mounted.
Like if False, send an email

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the result of the script to email, I would do something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

F=`mktemp`

A=`awk '{print $2}' /etc/fstab | grep -i "^/" | egrep -v '/etc/                 fstab|proc|sys|shm|pts'`

for i in $A; do grep "$i" /proc/mounts > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $i "FALSE"
    fi
done >"$F"

if test -s "$F"; then
        ( echo "To: you@example.com"; \
    echo "Subject: mount failures"; \
    echo "";  cat "$F" ) \
    | /usr/sbin/sendmail -fyou@example.com you@example.com
fi
```

Essentially, I'm assuming you don't need to know about the mounts that are ok, just those that need to be corrected.

I've found sub-shells `()` to be useful in cases like this, it could be done differently using a single `printf` statement but I felt this flowed better.

Comment: thank you for your reply, if there FALSE(Mount not mounted) it should an email with list of mounts not mounted(False)